# How do I change the $ function in jquery for another word for make it compatible with other frameworks

Tags: jquery

How do I change the $ function in jquery for another word for make it compatible with other frameworks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will un-assign the $ variable

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

But even more useful is being able to reassign the jQuery object to another terse variable, such as

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Of course you can make $j anything you want.

Answer (score 8):

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

Answer (score 2):

It's only an alias for jQuery - if $ causes you problems, use `jQuery` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the noConflict() method like so](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict):

```
var myjquery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
myjquery(document).ready( function() {
    // The usual...
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

use `jQuery.noConflict();`

if you still want to use the `$` shorthand in your jQuery code then you can use a self-invoking anonymous function to do so

```
(function($) {

    // $ is shorthand for jQuery inside this function :)

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can use closure, this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('div') //use regular $
})
```

However... WHY? Why do you want to load more than once library?

Comment: Ok, the thing is that Im using a jquery acordion, it cames with the jquery and the plug in, and every thing its writen with jquery insted of $, but a try to upgrade to a newer version of jquery, but the accordion stop working.

Comment: well... the problem may be with the accordion. However, if is a simple accordion, you may try this way: http://dev.iamntz.com/166/jquery-accordion-tutorial :)